# gridx shows the last record of my dynamic data

Tags: dojox.grid, dojo.gridx, gridx

hello am using grid to display dynamic data dojo, but what I get is that sample (n) times, but always shows me the last record, but if I do it with dummy data works well, I hope you help me with this issue.

`define(["js/module/modControllerPersona", "dojo/store/Memory", "gridx/Grid", "gridx/core/model/cache/Sync", "dojo/data/ObjectStore"], 
        function(modControllerPersona, Store, Grid, Cache, ObjectStore){
    var grid, store, data;
    var persona = new Array();
    return{
        datagridx: function(){
            modControllerPersona.persona().then(function(result){
                persona = JSON.parse(result);
                data = persona.items;
                store = new Store({data: data});
                var columns = [
                               {name: 'id', field: 'descripcion'},
                               {name: 'descripcion', field: 'id_Maquinaria'},
                               {name: 'descripcion', field: 'id_tipo_Maquinaria'},
                               {name: 'Nombre', field: 'kind'},
                               {name: 'Nombre', field: 'nombre'},
                               {name: 'Nombre', field: 'visible'}
                           ];
                grid = new Grid({
                    cacheClass: Cache,
                    store: store,
                    structure:columns
                }, 'gridNode'); 
                grid.startup();
            });`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this can help you, I had a similar problem. If you don't have a column id it doesn't work right. But if you adjust your store to something like this:

```
var store = new Memory({
    data:           data,
    idProperty:     'descripcion'
});
```

Perhaps the "new Memory" is not necassary. In my case this works (but I didn't tested it here again). I have no id but I have another unique field instead of this. I suppose it is because of your

> {name: 'id', field: 'descripcion'}

If you use instead of "descripcion" the name "id" I think it should work too.

Answer (score 0):

Just add "idProperty" for Gridx, I solved my problem

My dynamic data:
var data = [{"ID":"1","Số liệu thống kê":"Năng suất lập trình","Ngôn ngữ LT":"Java Web","Công đoạn":"Code - Review Code","Loại Project":"Customize/Full","Đơn vị tính":"KLOC/ManMonth","UCD1":"11.6","ITS":null},{"ID":"2","Số liệu thống kê":"Năng suất lập trình","Ngôn ngữ LT":"Java Web","Công đoạn":"Code - Review Code - UT","Loại Project":"Customize/Full","Đơn vị tính":"KLOC/ManMonth","UCD1":"4.6","ITS":null},{"ID":"3","Số liệu thống kê":"Năng suất lập trình","Ngôn ngữ LT":"Java Web","Công đoạn":"Code","Loại Project":"Customize/Full","Đơn vị tính":"KLOC/ManMonth","UCD1":"15.15","ITS":null}];

require([
                        'dojo/store/Memory',
                        'gridx/Grid',
                        'gridx/core/model/cache/Sync'
                        ], function (Memory, Grid, Cache) {
                            var store = new Memory({
                                data: data,
                                idProperty: 'ID'
                            });
Hope this help